# An echo operation includes some piece of text it should not include

Tags: shell, wildcards, echo

On a WSL Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) with composer I executed:

```
echo 2 * 3 > 5 is a valid inequality
```

It resulted in a file by the name of `5`, with the content:

> 2 composer-setup.php 3 is a valid inequality

I don't know why this `echo` includes the text `composer-setup.php` as well; it should have included everything from left and right besides 5 (the file name) as `echo` can have a single stream of text as its file name for redirection (no spaces allowed, as I understand, hence the `5` name).

Why is the `composer-setup.php` appears there between the 2 and 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've executed a commandline that has two shell-special characters in it: `*` and `>`. You saw what `>` did; the `*` is a wildcard / globbing character that picked up every<sup>1</sup> file in your current directory.  You have one file, named composer-setup.php in your current directory.

Quote your commandline; single-quotes work if there are no single-quotes in your text:

```
echo '2 * 3 > 5 is a valid inequality'
```

1: every file (or directory, socket, etc) that doesn't start with a period, unless you've set a shell option (such as dotglob) to specifically *enable* dot-file globbing.

Comment: @John, regarding your suggested edit, the wildcard/glob picks up directories and sockets and pipes, etc. -- not just "regular files"

Answer (score 4):

There are two things happening here...

First is that the shell sees the `*` character and replaces it with a list of files in the current directory.  This is known as "globbing"

In addition the `> 5` is seen as a redirection command.

so

```
echo 2 * 3 > 5 is a valid inequality
```

Is parsed as

```
echo 2 * 3 is a valid inequality > 5
```

This results in a file called "5" being created with the contents "2 *list of current files* 3 is a valid inequality".

To prevent this from happening we need to use quotes

```
echo '2 * 3 > 5 is a valid inequality'
```

The `'...'` prevents the shell from interpreting the special characters and displays the string you entered.